# Как то можно посмотреть или изменить заводские скрипты в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я не начинающий программист но и не мастер поэтому я всё таки хотел бы брать пример у профессионалов. **Как то можно посмотреть или изменить заводские скрипты которые писали создатели Unity?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотреть можно. Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference) на их репозиторий. Еще у них есть [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/), где, как я понял, можно найти исходники каких-то подсистем юнити.

Также, если работать в IDE с декомпилятором, например Jetbrains Rider, можно смотреть код прямо в ней. Это быстрее, но там некоторые функции все равно объявлены `extern` и код не видно.

А вот изменить это уже проблема. Даже если имеешь исходники, разобрался в них как следует и внес изменения, нужно будет собирать их вручную, смотреть как внедрять, и если даже все получится, то все равно при обновлении юнити нужно будет делать все заново.